# spring social get user email while authenticate

Tags: spring-social

We are using spring-social to integrate our application to facebook.
In OAuth2AuthenticationService, scope is empty.
We set scope as a input on form.But it was not work and scope could not be set . 
We could not get user email.

Are there any way to override "OAuth2AuthenticationService" scope variable ?

Not: Spring social verison is 1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

[We used spring social sample which contains security xml version](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase-xml)

```
            <form name="fb_signin" id="fb_signin" action="../auth/facebook"
                method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="scope"
                    value="email,publish_stream,read_stream,offline_access" /> 
                <button type="submit"> <img src="../images/social/facebook/sign-in-with-facebook.png" /> </button>  
                <!--  
                <input
                    type="image"
                    src="../images/social/facebook/sign-in-with-facebook.png"
                    align="right" />
                --> 
            </form>
```

Comment: Having the same issue. If I try to use `/connect/facebook` instead of `/auth/facebook` to authenticate, I see the following warning that turns into exception: `WARN : org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController - Exception while handling OAuth2 callback (Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Field or property 'name' cannot be found on null). Redirecting to facebook connection status page.`

Answer (score 3):

In your configuration, you need to specify `scope` as a property of the `FacebookAuthenticationService`. This is the service that handles calls to `auth/facebook`

In XML configuration, instead of:

```
<facebook:config app-id="${facebook.clientId}" app-secret="${facebook.clientSecret}"/>
```

use:

```
<bean id="connectionFactoryLocator" class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry">
    <property name="authenticationServices">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.social.facebook.security.FacebookAuthenticationService">
                <constructor-arg value="${facebook.clientId}" />
                <constructor-arg value="${facebook.clientSecret}" />
                <property name="scope" value="email" />              
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This works with Spring Social 1.1.0.M3

Answer (score 0):

To use the above XML config with Spring Social 1.1.0.RELEASE, use the minor edited version:

```
<bean id="connectionFactoryLocator" class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry">
    <property name="authenticationServices">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.social.facebook.security.FacebookAuthenticationService">
                <constructor-arg value="${facebook.app.id}" />
                <constructor-arg value="${facebook.app.secret}" />
                <!-- Important: The next property name changed from "scope" to "defaultScope" in 1.1.0.M4 -->
                <property name="defaultScope" value="email,user_friends" />              
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Only difference is in the property 'scope' which has been renamed to 'defaultScope' in the latest Spring Social version. Thanks to Victor Lyuboslavsky for sharing the initial config.