# Use of scope property for Facebook authentication

Tags: java, facebook, spring-mvc, spring-social

I'm writing a Facebook APP that need access to user e-mail and publish to timeline. I found these two links:

- [How to specify OAuth2 scope with spring-social-security SocialAuthenticationFilter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732858/how-to-specify-oauth2-scope-with-spring-social-security-socialauthenticationfilt)
- [spring social get user email while authenticate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110874/spring-social-get-user-email-while-authenticate)

telling me to use scope and defaultScope properties of:

```
org.springframework.social.facebook.security.FacebookAuthenticationService
```

But none of the two solutions is working.

The application uses spring-social-samples like starting point:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class FacebookConfig implements SocialConfigurer
{
    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, Environment env)
    {
        final FacebookConnectionFactory fbcf = new FacebookConnectionFactory(env.getProperty("facebook.appKey"),
                env.getProperty("facebook.appSecret"));
        fbcf.setScope(env.getProperty("facebook.scope"));
        cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(fbcf);
    }

    /**
     * Singleton data access object providing access to connections across all
     * users.
     */
    @Override
    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator)
    {
        JdbcUsersConnectionRepository repository = new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(dataSource,
                connectionFactoryLocator, Encryptors.noOpText());
        repository.setConnectionSignUp(new SimpleConnectionSignUp());
        return repository;
    }

    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource()
    {
        return new UserIdSource() {
            @Override
            public String getUserId()
            {
                return SecurityContext.getCurrentUser().getId();
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public Facebook facebook(ConnectionRepository repository)
    {
        Connection<Facebook> connection = repository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class);
        return connection != null ? connection.getApi() : null;
    }

    @Bean
    public CanvasSignInController canvasSignInController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
            UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository, Environment env)
    {
        return new CanvasSignInController(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository,
                new SimpleSignInAdapter(), env.getProperty("facebook.appKey"), env.getProperty("facebook.appSecret"),
                env.getProperty("facebook.canvasPage"));
    }
}
```

How can I set scope for required permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Class CanvasSignInController have a scope property that is used to request permissions on Facebook, just set this property with valid values an and everithing comes to new world.